# how to update value after button is clicked in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I tried this but value is not updating after each clicking of button

```
import tkinter as tk

win = tk.Tk()
max_amount = 0

def fun():
    global max_amount
    max_amount +=100

btn = tk.Button(win,text = 'Change', command = fun)
btn.grid()
t1 =str(max_amount)
label1 = tk.Label(win,text = 'Balance :$' + t1)
label1.grid()

win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import tkinter as tk

win = tk.Tk()
max_amount = 0
label1 = None #just so it is defined

def fun():
    global max_amount, label1
    max_amount +=100
    label1.configure(text='Balance :$' + str(max_amount))

btn = tk.Button(win,text = 'Change', command = fun)
btn.grid()
t1 =str(max_amount)
label1 = tk.Label(win,text = 'Balance :$' + t1)
label1.grid()

win.mainloop()
```

You need to reconfigure the label. This should do so. I hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter as tk

win = tk.Tk()
max_amount = 0

def fun():
    global max_amount
    max_amount +=100
    # use the config option to change the text of the label1 
    label1.config(text="Balance :$ "+str(max_amount))


btn = tk.Button(win,text = 'Change', command = fun)
btn.grid()
label1 = tk.Label(win, text = 'Balance :$0')
label1.grid()

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged here. The answer would be better if you described the change you made. Otherwise we have to read your code line-by-line and compare it to the original to see what's changed.

Comment: Please check the comment in the program for the explanation. Next time onwards, I will remember to do so

Comment: Yes, I see the comment. It's still better to put a description outside the code, so the reader doesn't have to read line-by-line to find the embedded comments.